# Jquery validation, setup error message on the element that shall be validated

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I would like to customize the Jquery validation plug-in, so i can set up the error message on the element that shall be validated. And then insert the error message in a div placed under the element that is validated (Because i have the div, is to avoid the the design is changed when the error messages is shown) Fx.:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Firstname" CssClass="required" errorMessage="Please fill out firstname" runat="server" />
<div class="divErrorMessage"></div>
```

I have tried this, but it isn't working (no erroe message is shown):

```
$("#form1").validate({
    onsubmit: false,

    errorElement: 'div',
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        error[0].innerHTML = element.attr('errorMessage');                
        error.insertAfter(element.closest('.divErrorMessage'));
    }
});
```

Thanks very much in advance!